# window.open to a link does not open in cordova app in windows phone 8

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8, inappbrowser

I have a cordova 3.4 project. I'm trying to make an app to download files from my tomcat server. The links are in the format `http://SomeIP/SomeFolder/SomeFile.xap`. I created an app with the download links with buttons having the following code on onclick

```
window.open("http://SomeIP/SomeFolder/SomeFile.xap","_system","location=yes");
```

What I'm expecting is that the file should start downloading when clicked.
However it is not responding on click event in Windows Phone 8 and shows the error message

`CordovaBrowser_NavigationFailed.`

The app is working perfectly in Android.

Is there any reason that the app isn't working in WP8? Are there any other permissions required? A workaround suggestion will also do.

Comment: have you installed InAppBrowser Plugin

Comment: Yes. It is installed.

Comment: Does the InAppBrowser in windows phone 8 allow the download of any files? Direct links from Google also doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed InAppBrowser plugin then use this source:

```
window.open("http://SomeIP/SomeFolder/SomeFile.xap","_blank","location=yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried InAppBrowser plugin, but in my iOS Cordova apps the window.open() works only if the event is related to a touch not to an automated event like onDeviceReady() or setTimeout().

Executing the window.open connected to an onclick() event works fine.